# QGraphicsView reset cached content properly

Tags: qt, caching, graphics, qgraphicsview

I am using QGraphicsView/QGraphicsScene to render a set of dynamic items (markers)
[image: markers on the view]

During for about 15 seconds everything is ok. But then appears an abnormal graphics artifact - parts of markers or even the hole of them do not disappear when I call `hide()` method
[image]
It seems that the problem is in view's cache, cause when I call `resetCachedContent()` this traces disappear.
Is there a way to manipulate views's cache? Is there a way to reset cached content right after cache is overflown?

**UPD**
1) I have tried to return adjusted bounding rect - that doen't help.
2) BSP sorting was turned off
3) I have also turned off any antialising with no effect
4) I switched caching mode to `NoCache` but this didn't solve the problem
5) The problem **was fixed** when I set `setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::FullViewportUpdate)` - thanks to @Joel-Bodenmann from the Qt forum!

Comment: Are those triangles custom items?

Comment: @peppe yes, they are

Comment: Triple check your shape / boundingRect implementations, they must take into account the pen's width and any antialiasing.

Comment: @peppe I know that. Triangle class was accurately designed. And as I mentioned, during the first 15 seconds nothing goes wrong - the same triangles are rendered correctly. I think the problem is in caching,

Comment: So if you disable caching everything is fine?

Comment: @peppe actially I didn't check. But triangles are rendere with Qt::NoPen and when I programmaticaly reset cached content scene becomes normal

Comment: Well that might simply be triggering a full update. The point is that QGV only repaints the "damaged" bits and a wrong shape / boundingRect would cause such issues.

Comment: @peppe I think if the problem is with shape/bounding rect, i.e. if I don't count pen's width the "wrong" bits would form something like triangles outline. But as far as you can see on the picture sometimes it is the full rectangle that is kept on the screen after element is hidden

Comment: Well now you have a few things to test :) Disable caching, try returning a bigger shape / boundingRect, try disabling the BSP index in QGV, try enabling full updates instead of partial updates.

Comment: @peppe I have updated my quastion

Comment: Forcing full updates however has a major CPU impact (or are you using a GL viewport?). I'd try to reduce this to a minimal testcase and submit a bug.

Comment: @peppe according to documentation to QGraphicsView::FullViewportUpdate "This approach is fastest when QGraphicsView spends more time figuring out what to draw than it would spend drawing (e.g., when very many small items are repeatedly updated). " That seems very close to my situation. And yes, I'll try to make a testcase for a bugreport